# Datejs error when upgraded to the latest version of Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, datejs

**Date.js error**

This occurs, when I updated to the latest version of Discord.js (14.0.3)

```js
/home/container/node_modules/datejs/src/core/parser.js:106
                        ords = s.match(/\b(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)\b/); // find ordinal matches
                                 ^
TypeError: s.match is not a function
    at Object.removeOrds (/home/container/node_modules/datejs/src/core/parser.js:106:13)
    at Function.parse (/home/container/node_modules/datejs/src/core/parser.js:147:47)
    at new Activity (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Presence.js:241:34)
    at /home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Presence.js:89:57
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Presence._patch (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Presence.js:89:41)
    at PresenceManager._add (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/CachedManager.js:36:18)
    at PresenceManager._add (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/PresenceManager.js:22:18)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/PresenceUpdate.js:29:41)
    at Object.module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:481:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:321:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1178:20)
Node.js v17.9.1
```

Comment: What if you log `s`? It means it's not a `string`.

Comment: Do you update a presence, activity or anything like that?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros the error says that it's a command that he uses to update the activity status of the bot